# Django - How to save javascript variable into Django Database via Ajax Call?

Tags: django

I want to save Final Score value into Database. How do I do it?

#### index.html

```
<div id="save_score">
  <input style="height: 40px; width: 120px; text-align: center; margin-left: 440px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Score" onclick="save_score()">
</div>
```

#### Test.Js

```
Final_score = 80;

function save_score() {
    $.ajax({
         url: '/save_score/',
         data: {'final_score': final_score},
         type: 'POST'
       }).done(function(response){
         console.log(response);
       });
}
```

#### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^save_score/', save_score)
]
```

#### views.py

```
def save_score(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        player = AddScore.objects.get()
        player.score = request.POST['final_score']
        player.save()
```

Comment: In the view you're going to need to tell it _which_ `AddScore` object to get!

Comment: But there isn't any objects in that model yet. I am trying to add value into the model.

Comment: Hello @tanzilshahriar if you are trying to create new object in model than do like this `player=AddScore()` and than rest of your code is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
    # create new instance of AddScore
    player = AddScore()

    # set the score
    player.score = request.POST['final_score']

    # create the record in the database
    player.save()
```